# having optional attributes in an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

let's say that I want to create directive to mimic a number input field (doing so just to learn about directives in general)

so, I create a directive like this

```
angular.module('myApp')

    .directive('inputNumber',function(){
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                label: '@',
                property: '=',
                readonly: '@',
                disabled: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: '/directives/numberInput.html'
        };
    })
```

and the templateUrl is this

```
<md-input-container>
      <label>{{ label }}</label>
      <input ng-model="property" type="number">
</md-input-container>
```

and my html text is this

```
<input-number label="Columns" property="controller.data.cols">
</input-number>
```

oddly enough this worked ;) I was quite impressed for a first attempt ..

Now, sometimes I want to add the min and max attributes for a number

as these are optional, what do I add to the directive js and html ?

I presume that I add

```
min: '@',
max: '@',
```

to the directive js, but what do I put into the html ?

```
<input ng-model="property" type="number" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}">
```

but then what happens if min / max is not supplied ?

thanks

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to append them with a question mark.

```
scope: {
  label: '@',
  property: '=',
  readonly: '@',
  disabled: '@',
  min: '@?',
  max: '@?'
}
```

The question mark declares the scope bindings as optional, allowing you to not include them at all in the markup if you don't need them. If you don't include them then the properties on your isolate scope won't be defined.

```
<input ng-model="property" type="number" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}">
```

Yes that is the correct way to pass values into those attributes, using the `{{}}` binding syntax. This is because the `@` binding is a literal binding. It will take the raw string value of that attribute and assign it to that isolate scope variable. By using the binding syntax, Angular will have resolved those bindings to actual values before your directive is parsed and reads those values in.

If you want two-way binding, then you would use the `=` binding symbol. That one tells angular that whatever you pass to that attribute should be a variable on the parent scope surrounding the directive. Angular knows at that point to create a two-way binding between that outer-scope variable and the variable on your directive's isolate scope. This way, if the variable in your isolate scope changes, so does the outer-scope variable, and vice versa.

```
<input ng-model="property" type="number" min="minValue" max="maxValue">
```

In that example your directive would expect `minValue` and `maxValue` to be variables already defined on the parent scope surrounding your directive.

I wrote a detailed [blog post](http://codetunnel.io/isolate-scopes-explained/) on isolate scope bindings last year. Hope it helps!

Comment: awesome. thanks for the response. Another issue I was tackling was that in some circumstances I would use ng-change="controller.changed()" in my <input> tag .. how would I pass that onto the directive ? I've tried ngChange: '@' and ngChange: '&' but angular complained about ng-model not being available ...